# One-time managed instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am coming from Azure; I want to deploy a one-time instance that does a heavy compute work and closes itself once done. In Azure, I was using an Azure container instance.

Is there an alternative to ACI in GCP? I was looking at Cloud Run, but I think it's just an alternative to App engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GCP Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) is a way to trigger running a container without worrying about the compute instances. And just the infrastructure to do so, there's little guidance on language or environment. Somewhat similar to Azure Container Instances.

App Engine is an SDK for some languages. A web app platform. Although note that [flexible environment cannot scale to zero](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features).

Either could work, depending on implementation details of how the event is triggered, and your desired development environment.

Comment: Can I attach a GPU to cloud run?

Comment: As a manged container service, Cloud Run doesn't expose compute instances. I don't see how GPU will work, but try containers with a GPU toolkit if you like. GKE node pools can have GPUs, but that would require you to configure a container cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest alternative is [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute), which allows you to use Google Cloud Platform's infrastructure to do heavy compute work through instances.

See [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) link to get you started quickly (there is also a [Windows](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-windows) version)